# sqlite data updation from one view to another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, uitableview

Hi I'm developing a eCommerce oriented for the first time I'm facing some issue. I have a product list in `UITableView` controller like this.

[image]

I have product list like in above image in that I can increase the no of products  add to cart
and in my add i have given option like update and cancel. In my Product list when user click the add button like come like this.

[image]

When user click add `UIbutto`n it will store in my local database `sqlite` and it will display in my cart list like this.

Now the problem is I give option like in cart itself they can cancel or update the order like that if user cancel the order in cart its not updating in my product list its still showing like product added and showing cancel button like same in image.

If i click on the image its showing null error now i want to do like if user cancel the order in cart list in my product list it as to show the add option not cancel please tell me how to do it.

My code I'm creating `UIButton` dynamically in `UITableView` in my Product list.

```
  -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     static NSString *cellIdentifier =@"Cell";


     meunuCell *cell =(meunuCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {

       cell = [[meunuCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }


     buon2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     buon2.frame = CGRectMake(264,20, 32, 32);
     buon2.tag=indexPath.row;


 if ([[count objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"yes"]) {


    [buon2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deletes.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     }
 else{
      if ([[count objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"no"]) {


        [buon2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"inserts.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      }

   }
      [buon2 addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod2:)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      [cell.contentView addSubview:buon2];
```

Insert and delete code of my product list methos.

```
  -(void)deletedata:(NSString*)query{
       NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
       NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
       NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bp.sqlite"];
        sqlite3_stmt *update_statement;
   if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &_myDataBase) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        const char *insert_stmt = [query UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(_myDataBase,insert_stmt, -1, &update_statement, NULL);
      if(sqlite3_step(update_statement)==SQLITE_DONE)
      {
        NSLog(@"Delete successfully");
      }
     else
      {
          NSLog(@"Delete not successfully");

      }
      sqlite3_finalize(update_statement);
      sqlite3_close(_myDataBase);
    }

  }


 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {


   pdi=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   [self openDB];
   NSString *sql =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM br"];
   sqlite3_stmt *statement;
   if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_myDataBase, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
          while (sqlite3_step(statement)== SQLITE_ROW) {

          char *field1 = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
          NSString *field1Str =[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field1];

          char *field2 = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
          NSString *field2Str =[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field2];

          NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",field2Str];
          NSLog(@"value%@",str);
          NSLog(@"pdi%@",field1Str);
          [pdi addObject:str];
       }

     } 
   }


  -(void)aMethod2:(UIButton*)sender
   {

 if ([[count objectAtIndex:sender.tag] isEqualToString:@"yes"]) {
      NSLog(@"deleted");
      int tag=[[sender superview] tag];
      NSString  *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"delete from br WHERE PID='%@'",[pdi objectAtIndex:tag]];
      [self deletedata:sql];
      NSLog(@"your deletion code here");
      [self.mytableview reloadData];
      [count replaceObjectAtIndex:sender.tag withObject:@"no"];
   }

 else
  {
      NSLog(@"inserted");

     //call your insert method
      NSString *inr=[intarr objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
      NSLog(@"%@",inr);
      NSString *item=[self.menuarray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
      NSLog(@"%@",item);
      NSString *cost=[self.menuarray1 objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
      NSLog(@"%@",cost);
      NSString *pid =[self.menuarray2 objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
      NSLog(@"%@",pid);
      int qt = [inr intValue];
      int mn =  [cost intValue];
      int total = qt * mn;
      tot =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",total];
      NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO br ('PID','NAME','COST','QUTY','TOTAL') VALUES ('%@','%@','%@','%@','%@')",pid,item,cost,inr,tot];
       NSLog(@"%@",sql);
      [sender setSelected:YES];

      [count addObject:@"yes"];

      [self Insertdata:sql];

      [count replaceObjectAtIndex:sender.tag withObject:@"yes"];
      [self.mytableview reloadData];

    } 

  }
```

I have used this above code for insert and delete in my product list its in that how to add the code like when delete the product in my cart list i want show the add option in my product list i have not getting any solution please help me out.

[image]

[image]